# How to simultaneously determine the range of x and base a when an inequality with logarithms holds?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

```
Log[a, x + 1] > Log[a, x - 1]
```

the inequality above is equation holds good under all circumstances

You can see the range of x

```
In[52]:= ForAll[x, x > 1, Log[a, x + 1] > Log[a, x - 1]]
Resolve[%, Reals]
Reduce[%, a, Reals]

Out[52]= \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ForAll]\), \(x, x > 1\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(Log[1 + x]\), \(Log[a]\)] > 
\*FractionBox[\(Log[\(-1\) + x]\), \(Log[a]\)]\)\)

Out[53]= Log[a] > 0

Out[54]= a > 1
```

How to simultaneously determine the range of x and base a when an inequality with logarithms holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Reduce[Log[a, x + 1] > Log[a, x - 1], {a, x}, Reals]
```

> `a > 1 && x > 1`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about simultaneous, but you can do this.

```
ieq = Log[a, x + 1] > Log[a, x - 1]
```

Looking at the result you can see `Log[a]` is in the denominator of each side, so multiply each side by that.

```
cond = MultiplySides[ieq, Log[a]]
```

Then `Reduce` the resulting set of conditions.

```
Reduce [cond, x]
*(Log[a] > 0 && x > 1*)
```

Comment: `cond` is not equivalent to `ieq` since we don't know the sign of `Log[a]`.

Comment: Mathematica covers both cases.